# MediaElement: show when loaded

Tags: c#, xaml

I have an image with the thumbnail of a video and a MediaElement with the real video, like so:

```
<Image Source="{Binding thumbnailurl}"/>
<MediaElement Position="{Binding currenttime}" MediaOpened="MediaElement_Opened" Source="{Binding videourl}" AutoPlay="True" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

With a property changed listener on the currenttime of the video:

```
private TimeSpan _currenttime;
public TimeSpan currenttime
{
    get { return _currenttime; }
    set
    {
        if (_currenttime == value) return;
        _currenttime = value;
        NotifyTimeSpanChanged("timespan");
    }
}

protected void NotifyTimeSpanChanged(string name)
{
    System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

With this eventhandler:

```
private void MyClass_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals("timespan"))
    {
        MediaElement me = (MediaElement)sender;

        if (me.Position.Milliseconds > 42)
        {
            me.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // show video now
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make a steamless transition from thumbnail to video when the video is at 42ms (first frame). The problem is that there never seems to happen a timespan changed event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property of `TimeSpan` (let's call it CurrentTime) and bind `Position` property of MediaElement to CurrentTime.

When CurrentTime changes, check that it's "bigger" than an arbitrary epsilon (let's say 42ms, which is about the duration of one frame). If it's bigger, do the visibility trick and stop comparison.

Comment: Good idea! You put me on the right track. Please check my updated question :).

Comment: @PhilippeMaes You need Position="{Binding currenttime, Mode=TwoWay}".